# Creating Auto Incrementing column in Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, counter, auto-increment

What is the easiest and most efficient way to create an auto-increment counter for every data row in google appengine?

basically I want to give every row a unique row_number so that I can overcome the issue of only being able to get the first 1000 results in a select query. I can thus add a counter lies between condition and mine all the entires in the table.

Comment: Have you tried using cursors? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to keep track of row numbers, you can use cursors instead.

For Java see:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors

For Python see:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors