# Check for a valid domain name in a string?

Tags: python, regex, api, domain-name

I am using python and would like a simple api or regex to check for a domain name's validity. By validity I am the syntactical validity and not whether the domain name actually exists on the Internet or not.

Comment: Seems it is already discussed [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128168/validation-for-url-domain-using-regex-rails).

Comment: For what reason? If this is let's say e-mail, the real validity should be checked by doing an DNS query for MX record, not by regexp.

Comment: Nope. There is zero benefit in doing lookups for known invalid names, it's just a waste of time and resources. Also you don't need an MX record to deliver email, an A record is sufficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any domain name is (syntactically) valid if it's a dot-separated list of identifiers, each no longer than 63 characters, and made up of letters, digits and dashes (no underscores).

So:

```
r'[a-zA-Z\d-]{,63}(\.[a-zA-Z\d-]{,63})*'
```

would be a start.  Of course, these days some non-Ascii characters may be allowed (a very recent development) which changes the parameters a lot -- do you need to deal with that?

Comment: can an identifier start/end with a hyphen?

Comment: Thanks! No, I don't I need some basic sanity check to ensure that it does not contain any blacklisted characters such as ' ! " etc.

Comment: Alex, I know you are an appengine Guru, please help me with this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894808/creating-auto-incrementing-column-in-google-appengine 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Amarghosh, per RFC 1035, yes: but the RFC also says "when assigning a domain name for an object, the prudent user will select a name" that's more prudent than that (and in particular has each identifier, which it calls 'label', start with a letter, and the whole domain name limited to 255 bytes). "Be conservative in what you generate and liberal in what you accept"!-) Since a RE no doubt has to do with "accept", better it be liberal.

Comment: @demos, I see you got a good answer to that other question (I was asleep by the time you asked it;-).

Comment: @alex yup :) 

I have 2 more for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906908/searching-through-model-relationships-in-google-app-engine

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906746/updating-model-schema-in-google-app-engine

Thanks!

Comment: You got two perfectly correct answers to those two questions, too (even though you apparently don't like them, I can't add anything to those answers).

Comment: ! is not necessarily 'blacklisted'. RFC2872 says that labels that are not used as hostnames (i.e. which do not map to an IP, for example in TXT or SRV records) may contain any printable ASCII character, so  _,;:'"!@£~$ and friends are all up for inclusion. This doc is good: http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html

Comment: @Synchro – your point is valid, but does it really apply to this question? It still seems that a valid domain name doesn't allow any characters other than the 'LDH' characters [[Domain Name System – Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_label#Domain_name_syntax)].

Comment: The question doesn't specify a context so I think it's not unreasonable to include - I use non-LDH names quite often for looking up DKIM keys, which use names like `blah._domainkey.example.com`.

Comment: This is a very good generic regex, but it must be noted that a domain name cannot begin with a dash.

Answer (score 6):

```
r'^(?=.{4,255}$)([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}$'
```

- Lookahead makes sure that it has a minimum of 4 (`a.in`) and a maximum of 255 characters
- One or more labels (separated by periods) of length between 1 to 63, starting and ending with alphanumeric characters, and containing alphanumeric chars and hyphens in the middle.
- Followed by a top level domain name (whose max length is 5 for museum)

Comment: This cannot store punycode. The shortest Cyrillic-script two-letter top-level domain is 6 letters in punycode.

Comment: museum is 6 characters, not 5.

Comment: It's a bad idea to hard-code the expected TLD length, especially now that IDN TLD's are coming out which are encoded and thus come out much longer than 5.

Comment: @Amarghosh does this check up 6 characters or 5 because the limit is 6 LTD

Answer (score 3):

Note that while you can do *something* with regular expressions, the *most reliable* way to test for valid domain names is to actually try to resolve the name (with [socket.getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo)):

```
from socket import getaddrinfo

result = getaddrinfo("www.google.com", None)
print result[0][4]
```

Note that technically this can leave you open to DoS (if someone submits thousands of invalid domain names, it can take a while to resolve invalid names) but you could simply rate-limit someone who tries this.

The advantage of this is that it'll catch "hotmail.con" as invalid (instead of "hotmail.com", say) whereas a regex would say "hotmail.con" is valid.

Comment: This is really a separate problem and not a good answer to the question. Given that DNS has been used for exploits in the past, checking that a string is at least vagely valid before using it is only sensible, plus it's orders of magnitude faster than a DNS lookup. This is akin to running code to see if it's malicious!

Comment: This can not be used for validating domain names that are about to be created, only for already existing ones.

Comment: @MichaelSmith if you're still wondering nearly a year later, it's because you can't do a DNS lookup on a URL like that - DNS is only for the domain name, so it gets confused by the extra protocol gubbins there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this:

```
(r'(\.|\/)(([A-Za-z\d]+|[A-Za-z\d][-])+[A-Za-z\d]+){1,63}\.([A-Za-z]{2,3}\.[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{2,6})')
```

to ensure it follows either after dot (www.) or / (http://) and the dash occurs only inside the name and to match suffixes such as gov.uk too.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are all pretty outdated with the spec at this point. I believe the below will match the current spec correctly:

```
r'^(?=.{1,253}$)(?!.*\.\..*)(?!\..*)([a-zA-Z0-9-]{,63}\.){,127}[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$'
```

Comment: spec [ref](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1035/?include_text=1)