# Updating Model Schema in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, model

Google is proposing changing one entry at a time to the default values ....

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html

I have a model with a million rows and doing this with a web browser will take me ages. Another option is to run this using task queues but this will cost me a lot of cpu time

any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Because the datastore is schema-less, you do literally have to add or remove properties on each instance of the Model. Using Task Queues should use the exact same amount of CPU as doing it any other way, so go with that.

Before you go through all of that work, make sure that you really need to do it. As noted in the article that you link to, it is not the case that all entities of a particular model need to have the same set of properties. Why not change your Model class to check for the existence of new or removed properties and update the entity whenever you happen to be writing to it anyhow.

Comment: Thanks! but how do I check in the model for a non-existent newer property? 

I want to run a query on the model with the new property and this does not work for the older entites which have not been updated with this new property

Comment: Any query that uses a property that does not exist on all entities will not return any entities that do not have the property. You can check for the presence of the property with the hasattr function if you are using Python.

Comment: so if I wanted to rename an existing property I would have to A)  add a new property with the new name, B) copy the data over from old property to new property, then C) delete old property?  ugh...

Comment: @nickfranceschina: Renaming a property of a datastore entity is an extremely costly operation with very little payback. Since the entities are internal to your application, why would you bother renaming them?

Comment: I dunno... sh!t happens sometimes and might have to rename them for consistency/ease-of-understanding.  just trying to understand the pitfalls

Answer (score 3):

Instead of what [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html) suggest, I would suggest to use low level GAE API to migrate.

The following code will migrate all the items of type `DbMyModel`:

- `new_attribute` will be added if does not exits.
- `old_attribute` will be deleted if exists.
- `changed_attribute` will be converted from boolean to string (`True` to *Priority 1*, `False` to *Priority 3*)

Please note that `query.Run` returns iterator returning `Entity` objects. `Entity` objects behave simply like `dict`s:

```
from google.appengine.api.datastore import Query, Put
query = Query("DbMyModel")
for item in query.Run():
    if not 'new_attribute' in item:
        item['attribute'] = some_value
    if 'old_attribute' in item:
        del item['old_attribute']
    if ['changed_attribute'] is True:
        item['changed_attribute'] = 'Priority 1'
    elif ['changed_attribute'] is False:
        item['changed_attribute'] = 'Priority 3'
    #and so on...
    #Put the item to the db:
    Put(item)
```

In case you need to select only some records, see the `google.appengine.api.datastore` module's source code for extensive documentation and examples how to create filtered query.

Using this approach it is simpler to remove/add properties and avoid issues when you have already updated your application model than in GAE's suggested approach.

For example, now-required fields might not exist (yet) causing errors while migrating. And deleting fields does not work for static properties.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help OP but may help googlers with a tiny app: I did what Alex suggested, but simpler. Obviously this isn't appropriate for production apps.

1. deploy App Engine Console
2. write code right inside the web interpreter against your live datastore

like so:

```
from models import BlogPost  
for item in BlogPost.all():  
    item.attr="defaultvalue"  
    item.put()
```