# cpp check if the string is a valid domain name?

Tags: c++, validation, dns

as title mentioned, is there a quick way to do that? I dont need a solid solution, anything that can differentiate, for example:

```
http://asdasd/
```

is not a valid domain name, where

```
http://asd.asdasd.asd
```

is a valid domain name.

I tried to search the solution, the closest(simple) solution is this: [in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894902/check-for-a-valid-domain-name-in-a-string)

But thats for python, I need to do in c++. Any help?

Can it be done by using "string manipulation" only? Like, substring?

Comment: Regular expressions? As Raymond Chen, would say, "now you have two problems"

Comment: hmmm.. Other than regular expressions? I saw a book from library, very thick, just for regular expression. I will study it in future, but not now, i just beginning c++ 2 days ago

Comment: Well, if you want to really be correct, look up the rfc and implemnent a parser for the grammar mentioned there

Comment: Lexer (parser) and state machine?

Comment: Quibble: `http://` is not part of the domain name; the domain name is `"asd.asdasd.asd"`.  Bigger quibble: `"asdasd"` *is* a valid domain name.  If you're on `foo.example.com`, and there's a host named `asdasd.example.com`, depending on the configuration, you can probably refer to it as just `"asdasd"`.  To be clear, you consider `asd.asdasd` to be "valid" even though there's no actual `asd` TLD (top level domain), right?

Comment: @akow: The thickness of books is not a reliable indicator of how difficult a topic it is. You can write arbitrarily thick books about _anything_, from how to use a pencil sharpener to how how to mow a lawn. The only difference is that thick books about regexes sell well enough to get published, and _that_ is purely a measure of how _afraid_ the book-buying public are of regexes. Which is completely without reason, as the basic concepts can equally well be covered in 4-5 pages of lecture notes.

Comment: You're trying to validate *domain* names or *host* names?

Comment: @Keith: I wish I could downvote comments: In `http://asd.asdasd.asd/`, the part `asd.asdasd.asd` is NOT a domain name, it's a hostname.  Hostnames can be interpreted relatively, as in your `asdasd.example.com` example, domain names can't.  And with the introduction of arbitrary TLDs, `http://asdasd/` could refer to a fully-qualified name rather than a relative one.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the info.  (I suspect the OP really wants to know about hostnames, and is incorrectly assuming that `http://asdasd` is an invalid URL, but that's a guess on my part.)  My comment was based on what I thought the OP was actually asking about; I was sloppy with the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 0):

Baring the fact that `http://...` is not a domain name but a URL, and that `asdasd` **is** as valid domain name if setup as a search domain (such as on local net), then purely checking for the string syntax can be done with a simple set of `strncmp`, `strchr` and `strstr` commands

```
char *str = "http://abd.xxx";

bool valid = strncmp(str,"http://",7) && str[7] && strchr(str+7,'.');
```

This should check that the string starts with http:// AND that there is more after the http:// and that the more after that contains a dot -- if you also want to handle where the URL contains an actual path like `http://expample.com/mypath.txt`, then the example become more complex, but you didn't specify if that was needed.

Alternatively, you can [use regex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex) and the pattern which you have from the python answer you point to yourself

Comment: It could be a valid local hostname, but it's also a potentially valid FQDN since the introduction of arbitrary TLDs.

Comment: No disagreement here -- the only way to really find out if a name is valid is by doing a host lookup -- but that is NOT what the OP is asking for -- the question is just about matching the pattern.

Comment: I think that is the correct answer to the question: "Can it be done using string manipulation?"  "No, a host lookup is required."

Comment: @Ben -- then you should put that in as your answer -- I may just vote for that :-)